# How can I check if an item exists in a inner list and get the list item in the corresponding outer list where it was contained?

Tags: python

I have a list like this:

```
[[0, [2]], [1, [4]], [2, [0, 6]], [3, [3]], [4, [0, 6]]]
```

I want something like this:

Check if 2 exists in the inner list(which can contain more than 1 item), then get the value of the corresponding outer list value(always 1 item) which is 0 is returned.

Input:

```
[[0, [2]], [1, [4]], [2, [0, 6]], [3, [3]], [4, [0, 6]]]
```

Output(some examples):

```
Search for 2
2 was found with 0

Search for 0
0 was found with 2 and 4

Search for 3
3 was found with 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## For the exact output

If you want the output to be exactly what you described:

```
values = [[0, [2]], [1, [4]], [2, [0, 6]], [3, [3]], [4, [0, 6]]]

search_value = 0
print(f"Search for {search_value}")

found = []
for outer, inner in values:
    if search_value in inner:
        found.append(outer)

if found:
    print(f"{search_value} was found with ", end="")
    print(*found, sep=" and ")
```

> Search for 0
>   0 was found with 2 and 4

## Sort version

If you just need to know the outer values, for which your search value was found:

```
values = [[0, [2]], [1, [4]], [2, [0, 6]], [3, [3]], [4, [0, 6]]]
search_value = 0

for outer, inner in values:
    if search_value in inner:
        print(outer, end=" and ")
```

> 2 and 4

## Even shorter version

Replace the two for loops with a list comprehension for a simple one liner:

```
values = [[0, [2]], [1, [4]], [2, [0, 6]], [3, [3]], [4, [0, 6]]]
search_value = 0

print(*[outer for outer, inner in values if search_value in inner], sep=", ")
```

> 2, 4

---

Works with Python `3.6+`

Comment: Maybe `print(", ".join([outer for outer, inner in values if search_value in inner]))` to make it compatible with Python 2?

Comment: @ChatterOne Yeah, should work. The only Python `3.6` thing I used there is the formatted string literal ("f-string").

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot. Good answer and well described.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a list comprehension, to check whether or not the sublists contain a given number, and then obtain the corresponding outer list values:

```
num = 0
out = [i[0] for i in l if num in i[1]]
'{} was found with {}'.format(num, ', '.join(map(str,out)))
# '0 was found with 2, 4'
```

Or for number `num=2`:

```
out = [i[0] for i in l if num in i[1]]
# '2 was found with 0'
```

---

The above answer assumes the inner lists are always in the second position. If that is not the case you could do instead:

```
out = [i[0] for i in l if num in sorted(i, key=lambda x: isinstance(x, list))[1]]
'{} was found with {}'.format(num, ', '.join(map(str,out)))
# '0 was found with 2, 4'
```

Comment: Your codes output doesn't match the desired output.

Comment: In what way does it not? for number `0`, it finds 2 and 4, which is the second example... @winklerrr

Comment: OP wants the output to be `Search for {search_value}` and `{search_value} was found with {findings, separated by and}`. Your output is just a list - not what OP asked for.

Comment: So only that is a reason for you to downvote..? Some simple string formatting, that should be basic enough for OP to check by himself... updated the answer. .. @winklerrr

Comment: Thanks, that's better! Here is your +1.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a dictionary from this list and then iterate by items in dictionary.

```
your_list = [[0, [2]], [1, [4]], [2, [0, 6]], [3, [3]], [4, [0, 6]]]
dictionary = dict(your_list)
# or just dictionary = dict([[0, [2]], [1, [4]], [2, [0, 6]], [3, [3]], [4, [0, 6]]])
for key, value in dictionary.items():
    if 2 in value:
        print(key)
```

Of course, you can wrap it to some method:

```
def some_fancy_name(dict, item):
    for key, val in dict.items():
        if item in val:
            return key
```

Comment: You're assuming that there's not going to be any duplicates in the first element though, like `[[0, [1]], [0, [2]]]`